# Regex for matching a previous group in the pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I can never seem to find any documentation on the regex for matching a capture group as part of the pattern. For example:

```
(\w\d\w):$1
```

..should match `a4b:a4b`

`$1` doesn't work, but I know it's something similar. Anyone know?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In a regex pattern, a backreference to the first capturing group is always `\1`, not `$1`.

Reason: `$` means "end of string" (or end of line, depending on context) in a regex.

In a replace pattern (which isn't a regex), some dialects allow `$1` (e. g. .NET, Java, Perl and JavaScript), some allow `\1` (Python and Ruby), and some allow both (PHP and JGSoft).

Edit: Since you wrote that you couldn't find any documentation on this, check out these overviews on regular-expressions.info:

- [Grouping and Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [Regex Replacement Syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplace.html)